# Python Scipy : "TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument"

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have the following system of 2 matricial equations where `a` and `b` are unknown vectors with for each 7 components. `D, D1, D2, P1, P2, F1, F2` are matrices (7x7).

```
# define the equations
def f(x):
    a = np.zeros(7)
    b = np.zeros(7)
    for i in range(7):
      a[i] = x[i]
      b[i] = x[7+i]

    # Looking for an endomorphism that has D eigen values
    D = a**2*D1 + b**2*D2

    eq1 = np.dot(P1.T*a**2,P1) + np.dot(P1.T*a,b*P2) + np.dot(P2.T*b,a*P1) + np.dot(P2.T*b**2,P2) - np.eye(7)
    eq2 = np.dot(F1,a*P1) + np.dot(F1,b*P2) + np.dot(F2,a*P1) + np.dot(F2,b*P2) - np.dot(a*P1 + b*P2,D)

    return np.array([eq1,eq2])

# inital guess
x0 = np.ones(14)
print('x0 = ', x0)
# solving
x = fsolve(f, x0)
print(x)
```

Unfortunately, at the execution, I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute_solving_Matricial_Equations_with_vectors_a_and_b_unknown.py", line 110, in <module>
    x = fsolve(f, x0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 139, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 196, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 32, in _check_func
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'f'.
```

I tried previously by doing at the end of `f` function :

```
return np.array([eq1,eq2].ravel()
```

instead of `return np.array([eq1,eq2]`.

But I get the same error. What might be wrong here?

I am handling with (7x7) matrices in my 2 equations but I have only 14 unknown (7 components for vector `a` and 7 for vector `b`).

### Update 1

Following the advice of @Warren Weckesser, I did to check:

```
# define the equations
def f(x):
    a = np.zeros(7)
    b = np.zeros(7)
    for i in range(7):
      a[i] = x[i]
      b[i] = x[7+i]

    # Looking for an endomorphism that has D eigen values
    #D = D1 + D2
    D = a**2*D1 + b**2*D2

    eq1 = np.dot(P1.T*a**2,P1) + np.dot(P1.T*a,b*P2) + np.dot(P2.T*b,a*P1) + np.dot(P2.T*b**2,P2) - np.eye(7)
    eq2 = np.dot(F1,a*P1) + np.dot(F1,b*P2) + np.dot(F2,a*P1) + np.dot(F2,b*P2) - np.dot(a*P1 + b*P2,D)

    print(' shape(a) = ', np.shape(a))
    print(' shape(b) = ', np.shape(b))

    #return np.array([eq1,eq2]).ravel()
    return np.concatenate((eq1, eq2))
```

and get as output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute_solving_Matricial_Equations_with_vectors_a_and_b_unknown_FOR_STACKOVER.py", line 89, in <module>
 shape(a) =  (7,)
 shape(b) =  (7,)
    x = fsolve(f, x0)
  File "/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 147, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 213, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 40, in _check_func
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'f'.Shape should be (14,) but it is (14, 7).
```

As you can see, it shows one time the print of shape(a) and shape(b) before failing.

Comment: You could also print the shapes of `eq1` and `eq2` in `f`.  I think that is where the problem is--apparently these do not have the shape that you expect them to.

Comment: you are right, I get : `shape(a) =  (7,) shape(b) =  (7,)  shape(eq1) =  (7, 7)  shape(eq2) =  (7, 7)` , So there are too many equations (49 if I understand well) for only 14 unknown (size(a)=7 and size(b)=7) ? Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: You might have to answer that yourself by double-checking your code.  I suspect you haven't correctly translated the mathematical equations into Python/NumPy code.  Someone might be able to help you if you can include in the question the mathematical formulas that you are trying to implement.

Comment: Would it be too difficult to include an [MCVE] in the question? Very hard to diagnose a runtime problem when the code you have posted is incomplete and can't be run and analyzed by others.